# How to get 'popstate' event listeners?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, popstate, single-spa

Is it possible to list all 'popstate' eventListeners?

I'm working around of microfrontend app and face an issue when I tried to use multiple single page applications with independent routing at same page. So problem I occured is incorrect behavior of App2 routing when I interact with App1, the best example is clicking on some link in App1, force App2 to use it own routing and I get 404 error in App2.

I tried to use `beforeEach` method of Vue router, but got issue with history push rollback.
I tried to modify router object from outside of my App2, but it just doesn't work.

So my next step is rolling deeper in popstate event and work around.
mb someone faced this issue or mb just give me a good advice. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So where is no way to do this, so we work around abstract mode in vue router